# How to access one controller instances in any of my controllers?

Tags: codeigniter, instance-variables

I am trying to access one controller Instance from another controller

I'm using the controller Named **Payment** but I needed methods from another controller named **Exam**, I need the methods from exams is there any way?
So anyone knows how to read the instances

Answer (score 0):

Through get_instance() we can perform this.
check it code below.

```
 $CI =& get_instance();
 $CI->get_product_name() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access functions defined in another controller, you can create that controller globally and simply extend that controller.

First you need to create a Controller named `MY_Cotroller` inside `application/core` folder and then create your `Exam` controller and extend `MY_Controller` in the same file.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Exam extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // your functions
}
```

Then in your `Payment` controller extend `Exam` controller.

```
class Payment extends Exam
```

You can call `Exam` controller functions from `Payment` controller as

```
$this->your_exam_controller_function();
```